# Index two vectors in loop to create name for new variables

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I want to create some new variables as recodes of existing ones but rename them based on a vector of variable names and a vector of numbers. In my real data, `thesevars` is a selection of variable names out of about 500 in the dataset.

I am clearly not referencing the variable names properly in the mutate call. A toy example is here:

```
dat <- data.frame(cbind(ql_1 = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 5)),
                        ql_3 = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 5)),
                        ql_4 = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 5)),
                        ql_11c = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 5))))

thesevars <- c("ql_1", "ql_3", "ql_4", "ql_11c")

num <- c(1, 3, 4, 15)

for(i in seq_along(thesevars)) {
  dat |> 
    mutate(paste0("surv25_", num[i])) = case_when(get(thesevars[i]) == 1 ~ 100,
                                                 get(thesevars[i]) == 2 ~ 75, 
                                                 get(thesevars[i]) == 3 ~ 50,
                                                 get(thesevars[i]) == 4 ~ 25,
                                                 get(thesevars[i]) == 5 ~ 0)
}

Error in get(thesevars[i]) : object 'ql_1' not found
```

So I want the new variable names to be:

```
surv25_1 
surv25_3 
surv25_4
surv25_15
```

with values recoded as above.

Comment: So are you looking for this? `setNames(dat, paste0('surv25_', num))` or `names(dat)[names(dat) %in% thesevars] <- paste0('surv25_', num)`

Comment: Apologies - I fixed the duplication. I just want to take a set of variables that need to be recoded and create a new set of variable names that are numbered by a specific sequence of numbers that I feed it.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly not an elegant solution as I'm a crap programmer but I think this gets the job done for what I want:

```
dat
   ql_1 ql_3 ql_4 ql_11c
1     2    3    2      3
2     1    2    3      1
3     4    1    4      4
4     3    2    3      3
5     4    4    1      3
6     4    2    2      3
7     3    1    1      2
8     3    2    1      2
9     4    3    1      3
10    1    1    1      3

# Create 2 equal size dataframes - one with existing data and one with blank data to be recoded
dat1 <- dat
dat2 <- dat
for(i in seq_along(num)) {
   varname <- paste0("surv25_", num[i])
   dat2[[varname]] <- NA
 }
dat2 <- dat2 |> 
   select(-1:-4)
# Loop over both dataframes simultaneously
for(i in seq_along(dat2)) {
   dat2[[i]]  <-  ifelse(dat1[[i]] == 1, 100, 
                         ifelse(dat1[[i]] == 2, 75,
                                ifelse(dat1[[i]] == 3, 50,
                                       ifelse(dat1[[i]] == 4, 25, 0))))
 }
dat <- cbind(dat1, dat2)
dat

   ql_1 ql_3 ql_4 ql_11c surv25_1 surv25_3 surv25_4 surv25_15
1     2    3    2      3       75       50       75        50
2     1    2    3      1      100       75       50       100
3     4    1    4      4       25      100       25        25
4     3    2    3      3       50       75       50        50
5     4    4    1      3       25       25      100        50
6     4    2    2      3       25       75       75        50
7     3    1    1      2       50      100      100        75
8     3    2    1      2       50       75      100        75
9     4    3    1      3       25       50      100        50
10    1    1    1      3      100      100      100        50
>
```